# How to get percentage coverage of raster values in an overlapping polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, ndvi

I have an NDVI image in ArcGIS 10.1 which is from -1 to 1. I have reclassified that image in 0 (range all negative value - non-green) and 1 (all positive value - green).

I have overlayed a 'fishnet' (rectangular grid) of 3 x 3 on image of 5 m resolution. In this case there are green and non green (1 and 0 values) in one fishnet cell.

I want to calculate the percentage coverage of the 'green' pixels within each cell of the fishnet grid (("AREA GREEN" / "AREA of CELL") * 100).

Comment: Please don't shout. I suggest that you edit your post to use mixed case (mostly lower), with more details on what you have tried.

Comment: When you make your edits, please explain what you mean by "get it in fishnet" and what a "VPixel value" is.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a shape file with polygons and the raster you can use the tool `Tabulate Area`  from `Spatial Analyst`.
The input dataset that defines the zones will be your 'fishnet' and the the dataset that defines the classes your raster.
The output will be a table like this:

```
value | value 0 | value 1
 ID1  |    0    |  2
 ID2  |    1    |  1
```

the first column will have the unique values of your 'fishnet', for each line it will display the number of cells of value 0 and value 1 for each 'fishnet' ID.